# Will a diamond helm be more protective against bullets?

Tags: material-science

Will a helm made entirely of diamond be more protective against bullets than standard steel or kevlar helmlets?

Comment: How do you expect this to be true..... Ignoring the absorbing effects, how would you foresee a diamond helm to actually distribute the local stress concentration when a bullet hits?

Comment: It would at least look cooler ;-)

Comment: Nobody'ies going to pay for that .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diamond, though hard, is brittle. The crystalline planes within it can shear relatively easily.

*"The toughness of natural **diamond** has been measured as **2.0** MPa m<sup>1/2</sup>, which is good compared to other gemstones, but poor compared to most engineering materials."* - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond#Toughness)

The [fracture toughness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_toughness#Example_values) of **steel** is about **50** MPA.m<sup>1/2</sup>. The crystals in it are formed into tiny grains and the crystalline structure has many disclocations. This gives steel strength.

For resisting bullets, dissipation of energy by elastic deformation is an important factor. I suspect diamond is much less elastic than steel.

Comment: Just as a note; for a thing such as a helmet not the strength per area is important, rather the strength per weight is the factor that should be compared. - As the weight is the most limiting factor for helmets (you do not wish to have a 20 kg helmet on your head). Maybe the stress per costs is important too, but then you touch ethical questions "what is the worth of protecting your head".